# How to make Outlook 2010 not warn on empty subject?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm using the beta of Outlook 2010, and am wondering how I can set it to STOP warning me on empty subject lines. My family and friends (as opposed to work) I generally send with no subject, and it is REALLY annoying that it constantly asks me

> "Really send with no subject?"

How can I turn this off?

Comment: Ironic - most people wanted the warning in older versions of Outlook

Comment: Yah, I mean, I can see the value in it for some people. But for example, my parents or brother or girlfriend who I may email several times a day, and don't need a subject for every email, so it gets tired quick having it try to second guess me every time! LOL . It really should have a "don't show this message again" checkbox on it.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/512-disable-outlook-2010-no-subject-prompt

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly! Now I'll just have to see if I can roll it into an add-in.

Comment: Is this really the best way to do it? Why is it not an option in Outlook itself?!

Answer (score 0):

It requires Exchange 2010 and Outlook 2010 to use MailTips which also has to be configured/Turned On in order to use. I tried to use a VBA script and that hasnt worked either.

Comment: That would explain why I don't have a MailTips section, as I am using Outlook against a POP account, not Exchange. Thanks for the clarification on OutlookSB's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Go into File tab, click Options, then in Mail tab of Outlook Options box, under MailTips, click MailTips Options and then click "Never Display MailTips".

Comment: I don't have a MailTips section. Under the File > Options > Mail section, I only have the following sub-sections: Compose Messages, Outlook Panes, Message Arrival, Conversation Clean Up, Replies and Forwards, Save Messages, Send Messages, Tracking, Message Format and Other.

Comment: This popup warning has nothing whatsoever to do with MailTips